# How to find the distance between two stars in a binary star system with given orbital period and velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, velocity

If we know the orbital period, and the velocity of both stars

Should I use Kepler's third law ?
$$T^2 = 4\pi^2r^3/(G \cdot M)$$ where $T$ is the orbital period, $M$ the mass of the star, $G$ the gravitational constant and $r$ the orbital radius

The center of Mass of a binary star system is:

$r_1M_1 = r_2M_2$ with $M$ and $r$ the mass and distance to center of mass of the star

Can I just use $v = 2\pi r / T$ to find the radius of both stars with $v$ the known velocity and $T$ the known orbital period, and then the distance between both stars would be $r_1+r_2$ ?

I'm just asking for some guidance, that's why I didn't provide any number

Your help would be greaty appreciated, thank you so much

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Astronomy__Cosmology/Celestial_Mechanics_(Tatum)/18%3A_Spectroscopic_Binary_Stars

Comment: @JohnDoty Thanks for the link, tough it seems quite advanced. I think I managed to solve it. I think i really need to use $v = 2\pi r/T$  to solve for the radius $r$ for both stars to get $r_1 + r_2 = r$, and that is the distance between both stars (when the distance is at its largest of course)

Comment: @JohnDoty There was a second question where they ask us to find the mass of  each star, and for that I think I can in fact use Kepler's third law $T^2 = 4 \pi^2 r^3 /(G \cdot M)$ to solve for $M$, and do that for both stars to get their mass

Comment: If someone wants to post an answer, feel free to do so, I will upvote and accept it, otherwise I will answer my own question tomorrow, maybe it will help someone else in the future